# Three20 HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS strange behaviours

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, three20

In one of my Three20 project, I have the **HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS**

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../three20 $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../three20
```

But according to this: https://github.com/facebook/three20

I have must the following line in the path..

```
../three20/Build/Products/three20
```

I have re-created a project using `ttmodule.py` and confirm `../three20/Build/Products/three20` is the **default** but I am not sure why my existing project left it out.

Now the issue is:

Q. Why the project can build without error (Simulator/Device), what do you think is the reason?

Comment: adding the build output might be a good idea to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Stephan, what do you mean by build output? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in pre xcode 4 days the build folder would be under the project source directory which made sense to add a search header in a relative manner.
Three20 copies the header files into a specific place as part of a copy build phase.

Since xcode4 is out the build directory moved completely out of the project source tree into a temporary place configured as $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR).
The reason you see 2 directories is because xcode generates 2 different paths for Archive builds and all the other kinds of builds (Run/Debug etc...)

> $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../three20 $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../three20

Notice that the manual instruction tells you to find that directory but it doesn't tell you where it is:

> Finally, we need to tell your project where to find the Three20 headers. Open your "Project Settings" and go to the "Build" tab. Look for "Header Search Paths" and double-click it. Add the relative path from your project's directory to the "three20/Build/Products/three20" directory.

Comment: This is not true. I am using XCode 4.2 (Derived data location/unique sub folder), I also need to include the path "../three20/Build/Products/three20" in order to build the app.

Comment: Howard, you're right - you should also add that relative path - but it's not enough. Back to the question - you need all three.